# React - why is this component not rendering anything?

Tags: reactjs, reactjs-flux

I am trying to render some child components in a parent component but nothing is rendering. I'm not getting any console errors but there is no render. I can't figure out why this may be happening. The application I am working on is built with React, using a flux architecture.

Here is my code:

Parent Component:

```
import React from 'react';
import TableWithDataHeader from './TableWithDataHeader.jsx';
import TableWithDataBody from './TableWithDataBody.jsx';
import TableWithDataRowForm from './TableWithDataRowForm.jsx';
import AppStore from '../../stores/AppStore';

export default class TableWithData extends React.Component {
    state = {rows: [], isEditing: false};

    componentDidMount() {
        let json = AppStore.getCells();
        let rows = this.state.rows;
        for (let key in json) {
            {rows[key] = json[key]};
        }
        this.setState({rows});
        console.log(rows);
    }

    handleEdit = (row) => {
        this.setState({isEditing: true});
    };

    editStop = (formKey) => {
        this.setState({isEditing: false});
    };

    handleSubmit = () => {
        console.log('hello');
    };

    render() {

        let {rows, isEditing} = this.state;

        console.log(rows);

        return (
            <div>
                <div className="row">
                    <table className="table table-striped">
                        <thead>
                            <TableWithDataHeader />
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            {rows.map(row => this.state.isEditing ? 
                                <TableWithDataRowForm formKey={row.id} key={row.id} editStop={this.editStop(formKey)} handleSubmit={this.handleSubmit} /> : 
                                <TableWithDataBody key={row.id} value={row.historycells.contents} handleEdit={this.handleEdit(row)} />
                            )}
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

RowForm:

```
import React from 'react';

export default class TableWithDataRowForm extends React.Component {

    editStop = () => {
        this.props.editStop();
    };

    handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.props.handleSubmit();
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>
                    <button className=""><i className="btn btn-default" onClick={this.editStop}></i>Cancel</button>
                    <button className="btn btn-success"><i className="fa fa-cloud" onClick={this.handleSubmit}></i>Save</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        );
    }
}
```

Table Head:

```
import React from 'react';
import AppStore from '../../stores/AppStore';

export default class TableWithDataHeader extends React.Component {

    addHeaders() {
        let headerArray = AppStore.getTable().columns;
        let headerList = headerArray.map((element, index) => {
            return (
                <th key={index} id={element.id} className="text-center">{element.name}</th>
            );
        });
        return headerList;
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <tr>
                {this.addHeaders()}
                <th></th>
            </tr>
        );
    }
}
```

Table Body:

```
import React from 'react';

export default class TableWithDataBody extends React.Component {

    handleEdit() {
        this.props.handleEdit();
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <tr>
                {this.props.histroycells.map(cell => {
                    return <Cell key={cell.id} value={cell.contents} />
                })}
                <td>
                    <button className="btn btn-primary" onClick={this.handleEdit}><i className="fa fa-pencil"></i>Edit</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        );
    }
}
```

The table header renders fine but neither the body of the table or the edit form shows up at all!

Any help would be much appreciated, especially examples!

Thanks for you time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this will help:

Inside your `<TableWithDataBody>`component, you try to access `this.props.historycells`, but this isn't passed as a prop.

You render your table rows with:

```
<TableWithDataBody 
  key={row.id}
  value={row.historycells.contents} 
  handleEdit={this.handleEdit(row)} />
```

Maybe if you change render to:

```
<TableWithDataBody 
  key={row.id}
  historycells={row.historycells}       // changed this parameter
  handleEdit={this.handleEdit(row)} />
```

UPDATE:
The line which loops over the props should still read:

```
{this.props.historycells.map(cell => {
```

PS: please also fix typo in `histroycells`.

Comment: So I did that but I am now getting TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined when trying to map through the props (row.histroycells), which I can't understand as it is an array.

Comment: See updated answer.Typo should be corrected + you should access `this.props.historycells`.

Comment: Yeah I got it working in the end, thanks for your help once again!

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in your code. `histroycells` in `TableWithDataBody` should be `historycells`.

Comment: Bummer, I'll take a closer look.